# Alignment with IEEEeqnarray

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Let's say I wish to use IEEEeqnarray to typeset an equation like the following:
[image]

Obviously I can do this by manually inserting lots of spacing commands, but I would prefer to be able to do this by specifying the column alignment when the IEEEeqnarray environment is started. So I have been experimenting with various alignment options such as

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{lCr}
```

but can I only achieve an equation typeset similar to 
[image]

How can I do this through the allignment option?

Comment: Do you want `y=x...` left-aligned and `+gg..` right-aligned? Is you `y=x...` really that wide? Perhaps a more practical example would be helpful.

Comment: If that is a single equation try `multline` environment from `amsmath`. See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134447/27635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you remember about ampersands?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}


\begin{document}


\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{lCr}
  y&=&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
 && {}+gggggggggggggggggggggg
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe not only big `C` for proper spacing around `=`, but also `{}` for proper spacing around `+` in the second line.

Comment: I remember the ampersands but have not seen their use in conjunction with {}. Thanks; just what I was after.

Comment: The {} is to position "+" as a binary operator, I suppose. If you remove it, it shifts the "+" a little bit closer to the ggggg.... expression. With the {} in place, it does not print anything, but it gives a little extra of space between "+" and gggggg...